# OpenLayers save canvas to image fails to hide layer

Tags: android, openlayers-3

I have an (Ionic 3.19) application with OpenLayers 4.6.5. I add a map layer (Vector) with some features.

**Problem:**
When I try to save an image of the map *with the layer not visible*, the image still contains the layer. *This only happens for Android*, not on PC or iOS.

Code (TypeScript):

```
layer1.setVisible(false)
this._map.renderSync();
// context is the map @ViewChild
var canvas = this.context.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0] // array length 1
var tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
tmpCanvas.toBlob(blob => {
    // Save image in blob
}, 'image/jpeg', 0.95);
layer1.setVisible(true)
```

This has been tested on Android 8.1 and 5.1 phones.

When I debug the layer1 visibility is indeed false.

If I toggle the layer's visibility on a tap event it works as expected:

```
layer1.setVisible(!layer1.getVisible())
```

I've also tested to use setOpacity(0) instead of setVisible but same result.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.